# Storing monthly analytics data for the last year

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to store the number of emails sent by users per month for the last 12 months, ie, a year. Each month will have 2 values, number of emails sent successfully, and the number of emails that failed to be sent for whatever reason.

My database is PostgreSQL which supports JSON data. I was thinking of something like this: one column that stores all the monthly data, with a structure like the following:

```
{
    "08-2019": {"successes": 348, "fails": 1},
    "07-2019": {"successes": 947, "fails": 7},
    "06-2019": {"successes": 428, "fails": 2},
    "05-2019": {"successes": 638, "fails": 5},
    "04-2019": {"successes": 354, "fails": 2},
    "03-2019": {"successes": 693, "fails": 0},
    "02-2019": {"successes": 461, "fails": 9},
    "01-2019": {"successes": 211, "fails": 1},
    "12-2018": {"successes": 414, "fails": 3},
    "11-2018": {"successes": 627, "fails": 7},
    "10-2018": {"successes": 241, "fails": 2},
    "09-2018": {"successes": 124, "fails": 4}
}
```

In other words, the keys are the months with years, and they store another JSON object with the number of successes and fails. This structure will be only updated when an email is sent. So lets say, during September 2019, an email is sent successfully. Because the key "09-2019" does not exist in the database, the oldest key is deleted, which is "09-2018", and a new key-value pair is added which is obviously `"09-2019": {"successes": 1, "fails": 0}`. When another email is sent in September, the key already exists, so it is simply updated.

Sometimes what will happen is that in some months, there will be no emails being sent, therefore, that month will have no data in the structure. I want to fix this issue during the query process. When a user retrieves this analytics data from the database, a new JSON data will be created where the keys will be the last 12 months, and each key will have a value of `{"successes": 0, "fails": 0}`. Then the two structures will be compared. The new JSON structure will be updated so that any key that is present in the database, that key's value will be replaced with the one from the database. This new structure will then be returned to the user so they will only see the data for the last 12 months.

My question is this: is this approach a good idea? I have no idea how analytics data is stored in production, and for my use case, I cannot allocate a lot of resources to store huge amounts of data because this is simply a side project with very limited capital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't suggest to go with JSON as you will face issue when data grows. If you are comfortable with only JSON then at least use JSONB data type where you can make use few indexes whereas JSON type column don't have proper index for improving performance.
2. JSON type column is suggested most of the cases when we do not know about the schema, but for your case you can use other type column efficiently. You can achieve same like following.

`date_keys` table will have columns like `id, date_value` and
`data` table will have columns like `date_keys_id, success_count, failed_count` where you can store data of each date.

In this way you can do query in efficient way though your table size grows. I am facing lot of issues with JSON that's why suggesting this way.

In date_keys table you can use `brin` index to fasten the querying and in `data` table you can use general type index `btree` to fasten querying.

Eg.

```
date_keys: id = 1, date_value = '10-2018'

data: date_keys_id = 1, success_count = 10, failed_count = 0
```